# Django how to pass user object in class based view pagenation?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

The default class based view pagination returning all object. I have an my account page for my each individual user where I need to show pagination number. By default pagination is same for all user. Let you explain little bit. If user A have 10 items and I listed 2 items per page then user A will be see total 5 page in his account which is fine but user B haven't any items and he is currently seeing only pagination number like page1,page2,page3... in his account because the current pagination returning all items from database. here is my code:

**views.py**

```
class BlogMyAccount(ListView):
      paginate_by = 10
      model = Blog
      template_name = 'blog/my-account.html'
      ordering = ['-id']
```

**#html**

```
{% for blog in object_list %}   
{% if user.id == blog.author.id %}  
 ....my code
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}   

<!---pagination code---->
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center mb-4">
                        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">First Page</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">← Back</a></li>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Page →</a></li>
                        
                        {% endif %}

                        {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
                        {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#!">{{ i }}</a></li>
                          
                        {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and i < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                        {%endif%}
                        {% endfor %}

                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

in function based view I am passing user object like this in pagination:

```
 notifications = Notifications.objects.all().filter(user=user).order_by('-date') 
 paginator = Paginator(notifications, 20) # Show 25 contacts per page.
```

I tried to apply same method by using context in my classed view  but didn't work. Pagination is same for all user in class based view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the queryset the same way you did in FBV. Override get_queryset() to only return objects associated with your requesting user.

```
class BlogMyAccount(ListView):
    paginate_by = 10
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/my-account.html'
    ordering = ['-id']
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Blog.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

Also you dont need to call .all() on Notifications.objects, it is already a queryset, Notifications.objects.filter() is okay.

If possible, move ordering to the models.py file, as in:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-id']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `get_querset` method, and by using a `super()` call, let Django do the `.order_by` clause for us:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class BlogMyAccount(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
      paginate_by = 10
      model = Blog
      template_name = 'blog/my-account.html'
      ordering = ['-id']

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #                 ↓ will take care of the ordering
        return super().get_querset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            author=self.request.user
        )
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).